# Elements moving around when a window is resized?

Tags: html, css

I know this question has been asked to death, but I honestly can't seem to solve this problem, whenever I resize my browser window, the images on the screen seem to want to move around, I'd rather they stay in one place and not be sliding into each other, when the window is resized, the images should remain in place and should be found by using a horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of the page.

HTML

```
<head>
    <title>CSGO Clash - Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet.css"/>
</head>

<body>
<a href="index.html"><img class="logo" align="left" src="CSGO%20Clash.png" alt="CSGO Clash" style="width:300;height:150;"></a>
<a href= "https://steamcommunity.com/openid/loginopenid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.sreg=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fextensions%2Fsreg%2F1.1&openid.sreg.optional=nickname%2Cemail%2Cfullname%2Cdob%2Cgender%2Cpostcode%2Ccountry%2Clanguage%2Ctimezone&openid.ns.ax=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fsrv%2Fax%2F1.0&openid.ax.mode=fetch_request&openid.ax.type.fullname=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson&openid.ax.type.firstname=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson%2Ffirst&openid.ax.type.lastname=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2FnamePerson%2Flast&openid.ax.type.email=http%3A%2F%2Faxschema.org%2Fcontact%2Femail&openid.ax.required=fullname%2Cfirstname%2Clastname%2Cemail&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Fcsgorumble.com%2Fauth%2Fsteam%2Freturn&openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2Fcsgoclash.com%2F" >
<img class="ssi" align="right" alt="Steam LogIn" src="SteamSignIn.png" style="width:256;height:112;"></a>



<div class="tablediv"> 
<table class="table">
   <TABLE background="background.png" align="center" width=1210 height=473>
   <TD width=302.5px id="space">Current Pot</TD>
   <TD width=302.5px id="space">Participants</TD>
   <TD width=302.5px id="space">Items</TD>
   <TD width=302.5px id="space">Chat</TD>


 </table>
</div>

</body>
```

CSS

```
body{
background-color:38445A;}

.logo{
position: absolute;
top: 30;
left:30;}

.ssi{
position: fixed;
top: 30;
right: 30;}

.tablediv{
position: absolute;
top: 200;
width: 90%;
margin: 5%;}

.table{
text-align:center; 
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:auto; 
width:1210;}
```

Comment: Can you recreate issue in https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Please take a look at: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html and https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values

Comment: Get in the habit of [validating your HTML](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input). You have a `table` tag that is never closed. This may or may not be part of the problem.

Comment: where is the table tag?

Comment: Where is the `<tr>` tag?

Comment: realized it was missing, changed it a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="yourContainer">
        <a href="#" class="floatLeft">
            <img width="300" height="150" src="CSGO%20Clash.png" alt="CSGO Clash" >
        </a>
        <a href= "#" class="floatRight" >
            <img width="256" height="112" align="right" alt="Steam LogIn" src="SteamSignIn.png">
        </a>

        <div class="tablediv"> 
            <table class="table">
               <TD width=302.5px id="space">Current Pot</TD>
               <TD width=302.5px id="space">Participants</TD>
               <TD width=302.5px id="space">Items</TD>
               <TD width=302.5px id="space">Chat</TD>
             </table>
        </div>
     </div>
</body>
```

some additional CSS:

```
.yourContainer
{
    min-width: 600px;
}
.floatLeft
{
    float: left;
}
.floatRight
{
    float: right;
}
.clear
{
    clear: both;
    float: none;
}
```

As you can see, the "yourContainer"-class defines a min-width, which should meet your requirements.

Maybe you also want to take a look at [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), which includes a quite comfortable [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic).

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working, for one, my background color is now whitened, and the images still move freely about when the page is resized.

Comment: Of course, since I did not provide the full file here. Just change YOUR code with my suggestions; insert the css classes into your css-file and edit your <body> in your html file like i suggested. If you just copy and save above code, you don't have a <head> to include your css file.

Comment: Oh! Right! my bad, I'm very tired, thankyou very much, I'm very new to html and CSS, just started today, thanks for your help, I'll try and work out how everything you've said works.